# Why hasn't EventListenerList been replaced? (Or: what are the pitfalls in replacing it?)

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

Our legacy app is stuck with a terrible framework (okay, I'll name names, it's Tapestry 4) that involves a ridiculous number of `EventListeners` (~100,000) for the simplest operations. I'm guessing this is beyond what `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList` was ever meant to handle, and in this unfortunate use case it's causing us some nasty performance headaches.

I spent a couple of hours whipping up the fairly naive `HashMap/ArrayList`-based replacement below, and it's massively faster in almost every way:

Add 50,000 listeners:

- `EventListenerList` > 2 seconds
- `EventListenerMap` ~ 3.5 milliseconds

Fire event to 50,000 listeners:

- `EventListenerList` 0.3-0.5 milliseconds
- `EventListenerMap` 0.4-0.5 milliseconds

Remove 50,000 listeners (one at a time):

- `EventListenerList` > 2 seconds
- `EventListenerMap` ~280 milliseconds

Firing might be just a hair slower, but modification is enormously faster. Admittedly, the situation this framework has put us in is pathological, but it still seems like `EventListenerList` could have been replaced a long time ago. Obviously there are issues with the public API (e.g., it exposes its raw internal state array), but there must be more to it than that. Maybe there's multithreaded cases where `EventListenerList` is much safer or more performant?

```
public class EventListenerMap
{

    private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = lock.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

    private Map<Class, List> llMap = new HashMap<Class, List>();

    public <L extends EventListener> void add ( Class<L> listenerClass, L listener )
    {
        try
        {
            writeLock.lock();
            List<L> list = getListenerList( listenerClass );
            if ( list == null )
            {
                list = new ArrayList<L>();
                llMap.put( listenerClass, list );
            }
            list.add( listener );
        }
        finally
        {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public <L extends EventListener> void remove ( Class<L> listenerClass, L listener )
    {
        try
        {
            writeLock.lock();
            List<L> list = getListenerList( listenerClass );
            if ( list != null )
            {
                list.remove( listener );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <L extends EventListener> L[] getListeners ( Class<L> listenerClass )
    {
        L[] copy = (L[]) Array.newInstance( listenerClass, 0 );
        try
        {
            readLock.lock();
            List<L> list = getListenerList( listenerClass );
            if ( list != null )
            {
                copy = (L[]) list.toArray( copy );
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
        return copy;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <L extends EventListener> List<L> getListenerList ( Class<L> listenerClass )
    {
        return (List<L>) llMap.get( listenerClass );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 crazy(iest) question of this month, Q about (for the simplest operations) are every of steps separate or they are chained, from tree or semaphore, if yes then another crazy(iest) suggestion, use EventHandler and to build path in String form on runtime, then there maybe not required to hold bunch of methods in memory, phaaa I love this idea, that came from your question, let RPG live forever (then same crazy endless code)

Comment: Do you have a typo in the relative firing times? You report that your implementation might be "just a hair slower" at 0.4 _milliseconds_ vs. 0.3 _seconds_ for the `EventListenerList`.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks!

Comment: @greedybuddha not the way `EventListenerList` handles them.

Comment: @mKorbel not sure I completely follow you but I suspect it would be possible to determine the set of event handlers from the top down at event firing time; that said, that would involve knowing way more than I want to about the insanity that created 100,000 event listeners in the first place...

Comment: register/loading 100k events in memory is the same as loading database table to visible GUI, this huge numbers of event required some data background, if from database, then lets this intended computations for SQL engine, nothing around isn't better optimalized, sure maybe code in Assembler or Cobol, but on specific platform

Comment: Swing is single threaded so you shouldn't need to lock at all (unless you app breaks that rule).
As for why it is not replaced, simply not needed since expected listener count in normal Swing programs is maybe no more than 10, not 100000

Comment: @WalterLaan You shouldn't, but (1) I'll bet very little of the Swing code out there takes care to only add/remove listeners in the EDT and (2) EventListenerList is synchronized up the wazoo.

Comment: @mKorbel it's not from a database, it's a combination of compiled code (mostly abstract classes) and two or three flavors of XML template files. The 100K listeners are all component objects representing everything from strings to conditionals. (How that number gets into five digits, let alone six, I have no idea. Believe me, I would never in a million years have architected this framework this way.)

Comment: 1) good, then XML template can hold required Listener, inside nodes tree is possible to hold theoretically the same infos as in the database, 2) comment by @WalterLaan is based on your deepest knowledges about Java, Swing, Generics, have to accepting that, take that as good busines concept

Comment: I want ask about the "readLock" in
`public <L extends EventListener> L[] getListeners ( Class<L> listenerClass )`

Don't think it is necessary becaust only reading.If you are worrying about writing at same time,you sould use writeLock instead of readLock.

Comment: The read lock's there because I'm not convinced it's safe to call `ArrayList.toArray(T[])` while the list is being modified. If it's guaranteed that nobody can slip in and modify `ArrayList.size` after `toArray()` gets the pointer to `ArrayList.elementData`, then the read lock could be removed, but I'm not enough of a byte code expert to feel confident there. (Also this way it's safe even if you switch to a different `List` implementation, though I don't know why you'd want to.)

Comment: This method only read data of list, We don't (shouldn't) **modify** data of list in reading operation. Even though, in that case——"...call ArrayList.toArray(T[]) while the list is being modified..." or "...modify ArrayList.size after toArray() gets the pointer ...", like i metioned above, write lock should be used instead of read lock. Thank you for your answer and sorry for my obsession with this little point.

Comment: The write lock is exclusive, and it is what is used for writes. Only one thread at a time can acquire the write lock. The read lock is not exclusive -- any number of threads can acquire the read lock -- but it blocks other threads from acquiring the write lock. This makes sure we don't get those modifications in the middle of a read. See the JavaDoc for [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: I was mistaken about those two locks, thought two single ReentrantLock. I get it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a question of optimization.  Swing's EventListenerList assumes:

- The number of Listeners on a list is very small
- The number of ListenerLists could be very large
- Add/remove events are very infrequent

Given those assumptions, the computational cost of adding and removing items is negligible, but the memory cost of having those lists sitting around could be significant.  That's why `EventListenerList` works by allocating an array that is exactly large enough to hold the Listeners, thus having the smallest possible memory footprint.  ([As the docs note](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), it doesn't even allocate anything until the first Listener is added, to make sure you don't waste space if there are no Listeners.)  The downside of this is that every time a new element is added, it re-allocates the array and copies all the old elements, giving you astronomical costs when you have too many listeners.

(Actually, it's not quite as memory-efficient as possible; the list is {Type,Listener} pairs, so if it was an array of arrays it would be slightly smaller in some cases.)

As for your solution: `HashMap`s over-allocate memory to ensure efficient hashing.  Likewise, the default `ArrayList` constructor allocates space for 10 elements and grows in chunks.  In your bizarre code-base where there are 100k listeners on each list, this extra memory is a tiny addition to the memory you're using to hold all the listeners.

Under a lighter Listener load, though, your implementation costs 16 pointers for every empty list (the default allocation of `HashMap`), 26 pointers for an `EventListenerMap` with one element, and 36 pointers for a map with two elements of different classes.  (This is not counting the rest of the `HashMap` and `ArrayList` structure size.)  For those same cases, `EventListenerList` costs 0, 2, and 4 pointers respectively.

It seems like a huge improvement for the code you've got.